# Socket Server which listen to two specific ports

Tags: c, sockets

I need to have a socket which listen to two specific ports. When a client request comes how do i know it is from which port

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a s/w company ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is meaningless. There is no such thing as a 'socket which listens at two specific ports'. You need two sockets. Then the socket itself tells you which port the data came from.

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind a single socket to several ports. The socket is bound only once with a "port-address" pair. You need to create several listening sockets and bind each of them to the local address (can be the same for them) and a port (which are different).

Comment: thanks..i was not aware.. just learning